# What's this icon that looks like a frequency wave with a slash through it on my Motorola One 5G Ace (T-Mobile)?

Tags: notification-icons, motorola

I have a newer Motorola One 5G Ace, provider is T-Mobile.  I've traveled away from home, still in the US though, and have a strange icon (next to my battery indication) that doesn't go away.  It looks like a frequency band wave, (squiggly up and down and across) with a bar through it.  I would describe it as a "No frequency" icon.

[image]

I can't find anything about it, or how it might be indicative of a phone signal problem.  It popped up suddenly and now my camera doesn't work, nor does any voice features (dictation into Google or notes).  Rebooting doesn't take it way.

Update:  I'm back at home and still have the icon and camera/dictation problem so it's not something to do with roaming or being away from T-Mobile's network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The strikethrough frequency wave notification icon indicates [sensors off](https://source.android.com/docs/core/interaction/sensors/sensors-off).** It can be used to disable sensors, including *the camera and microphone*.

> When in airplane mode, devices can still access some sensors to enable specific functionality, such as screen rotation and taking pictures. Android 10 provides a developer options setting to shut off all sensors in a device. This feature [...] gives users a way to control the sensors in their device.
>
> When a developer or user enables **Sensors off** in developer options (**Settings > System > Developer options > Quick settings developer tiles**), a new tile appears in the quick settings tray. They can use the tile to *prevent apps from accessing the camera, microphone, and all sensors* managed by the `SensorManager` class.

<sup>(Italic emphasized added)</sup>